# How can I get to the office when I've chosen the "try later" option?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I had a bestseller and I had the option to move to an office but I wanted to wait. But now I am ready, how can I move now to the office? I can't find any option - neither in the pop up or in the main menu.

Comment: Feel free to make your edit an answer to the question instead, we have no problem with people answering their own questions here.  Someone else might wonder the same thing!  If you really don't think the question deserves an answer, you can just choose to Delete it.

Answer (score 12):

The game is programmed to give you the option periodically, a few weeks after you decline the first offer.  It always comes back.